# Android Kernel Compiling - cp: cannot create regular file '..img/zImage': No such file or directory error

Tags: android, makefile, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm trying to compile kernel from source but I'm facing a simple problem which is annoying.

**My enviroment:**
Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64 / Kernel source ver: 3.0.40 / CC: arm-linux-androideabi-4.8

when i try to get kernel image with "make" I'm getting this output:

```
  SHIPPED arch/arm/boot/compressed/lib1funcs.S
  AS      arch/arm/boot/compressed/lib1funcs.o
  LD      arch/arm/boot/compressed/vmlinux
  OBJCOPY arch/arm/boot/zImage
  Kernel: arch/arm/boot/zImage is ready
          => zImage, copy to ../img/zImage
cp: cannot create regular file '../img/zImage': No such file or directory
/home/username/Desktop/KERNEL/src/arch/arm/boot/Makefile:58: recipe for target 'arch/arm/boot/zImage' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/boot/zImage] Error 1
/home/username/Desktop/KERNEL/src/arch/arm/Makefile:280: recipe for target 'zImage' failed
make: *** [zImage] Error 2
```

Image file is creating in *arch/arm/boot/* directory but it has lock icon on it.

**What i tried?**
I tried to compile as superuser (same error)

can someone help me about that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share codes in src/arch/arm/boot/Makefile +58 ?
however, if arch/arm/boot/zImage is already made, you may be able to skip rest of build process